# Vizframe column chart label selection item count issue

Tags: sapui5

I encounter with strange test case in which even if there aren't any data in last two column of Vizframe column chart and if you click on label the popup shows "4 Items selected". Is there any way to show actual selected items? like in this case, it should be "2 Items selected".

[image]

Code

```
<viz:Popover id="idPopOver"></viz:Popover>
        <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
            height='100%' width="100%" vizType='column'>
            <viz:dataset>
                <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/milk}">
                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Week"
                            value="{Week}" />
                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                    <viz.data:measures>
                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Revenue"
                            value="{Revenue}" />
                    </viz.data:measures>
                </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
            </viz:dataset>

            <viz:feeds>
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure"
                    values="Revenue" />
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension"
                    values="Week" />
            </viz:feeds>
        </viz:VizFrame>
```

Data

```
{
   "milk":[
      {
         "Week":"Spring '16",
         "Revenue":325020.45
      },
      {
         "Week":"Summer '16",
         "Revenue":464000.3
      },
      {
         "Week":"Autumn '16",
         "Revenue":0
      },
      {
         "Week":"Winter '16",
         "Revenue":0
      }
   ]
}
```

I am expecting that when label is selected and popup is appeared that time the final item count should be based on available details, like in above case out of 4 items 2 records contains zero as value in Revenue property. so it should ideally show "2 items selected" instead of "4 items selected"

Configurations which I tried:

```
let oVizFrame = this.oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");
            oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
                general : {
                    groupData : false
                },
                plotArea: {
                    dataLabel: {
                        formatString: formatPattern.SHORTFLOAT_MFD2,
                        visible: true,
                        showTotal: true
                    }
                },
                legend : { visible : true },
                valueAxis: {
                    label: { formatString: formatPattern.SHORTFLOAT },
                },
                categoryAxis: { title: { visible: false  } },
                title: { visible: true },
                tooltip: { visible: true },
                interaction: { selectability: { mode: 'inclusive' } }
            });
```

Comment: Weird,
So before using a CustomDataControl for make your own popover you can try to debug to find how the count is made internally.
What do "interaction: { selectability: { mode: 'inclusive' } }"  on your viz config ?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using a custom popover. When you click on legend label you can refer below logic.

```
fnCustPopover : function (data) {
    let oView = this.getView(),
        oViewModel = oView.getModel('view'),
        aMilkData = oViewModel.getProperty("/milk"),
        i = 0, iCount = 0, sOriginalText = "", iNumberOfDigit = 1;

    if (data.data.val) {
        let values = data.data.val, divStr = "", svg;
        svg = "<svg width='10px' height='10px'><path d='M-5,-5L5,-5L5,5L-5,5Z' fill='" + data.data.color + "' transform='translate(5,5)'></path></svg>";
        divStr = divStr + "<div style = 'margin: 15px 30px 0 10px'>" + svg + "<b style='margin-left:10px'>" + values[3].name + "</b></div>";
        divStr = divStr + "<div style = 'margin: 5px 30px 0 30px'>" + values[3].value + " " + this.getResourceBundle().getText("lbl.days") + "</div>";
        return new HTMLControl({ content:divStr});
    } else {    // When legend label is selected
        let divStr = "", svg;
        svg = "<svg width='10px' height='10px'><path d='M-5,-5L5,-5L5,5L-5,5Z' fill='" + data.data.color + "' transform='translate(5,5)'></path></svg>";
        divStr = divStr + "<div style = 'margin: 15px 30px 0 10px'>" + svg + "<b style='margin-left:10px'>" + data.target.__data__.measureNames + "</b></div>";

        sOriginalText = this.oPopOver._Popover._oSelectedBar.getContentMiddle()[0].getText();
        if (typeof sOriginalText[1] === "number") {
            iNumberOfDigit = 2;
        }
        sOriginalText = sOriginalText.substring(iNumberOfDigit);
        while (i < aMilkData.length) {
            if (aMilkData[i][data.target.__data__.measureNames] > 0) {
                divStr = divStr + "<div style = 'margin: 5px 30px 0 30px'>" + aMilkData[i].Months + "<span style = 'float: right'>" + aMilkData[i][data.target.__data__.measureNames] + "</span></div>";
                iCount++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        this.oPopOver._Popover._oSelectedBar.getContentMiddle()[0].setText(iCount + sOriginalText);     // Customising to handle proper count for selected items in popup

        return new HTMLControl({ content:divStr });
    }
}
```

Refer or implement only if you are almost give-up. Ideally not recommended because logic contains use of private variables which might change with the upcoming versions.